# Best practice when inserting a many-to-many relationship in a transaction using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with bookshelfjs (knex)

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Alright so I'm working on a personal project with which you can make "to watch" lists. A user can look up a movie they've heard is good using a public API (TheMovieDB) and add it to their watchlist. Whenever a movie is added I save the data to a database. I use the following tables (excluding columns that aren't relevant to the question):

users

- ID

movies

- ID (PK)
- tmdbID (Unique)

movies_users

- ID (PK)
- movie_ID (FK references ID in movies table)
- user_ID (FK references ID in users table)

genres

- ID (PK)
- Name (Unique)

genres_movies

- ID (PK)
- genre_ID (FK references ID in genres table)
- movie_ID (FK references ID in movies table)

I went with MariaDB because I wanted the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE functionality, because I don't have any original data in this database, so for example when someone wants to add a movie to their database, but I already have this movie in the database, I just want to add a new row in the movies_users table. At the same time I also use that functionality when it comes to genres.

Language wise I use NodeJS with BookshelfJS.

Now I'm not in the slightest an expert on SQL so I'm not sure if my way of working is the most optimal one. Furthermore, I'm not that familiar with Promises. This is the code I use when adding a movie to the database: http://codeshare.io/BPWDV.

I use a transaction because I assume it's the safest way? I also had to use knex.raw (http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Queries) so I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Basically this is what's going on:

1. I try to INSERT a movie into the movies table, depending on any existing rows
2. If the movie was already in the table I look for the ID of the movie so I can use it in the movies_users table. I don't have to look for the ID if the movie wasn't in there originally because I get back the ID of the inserted row.
3. I INSERT a row into the movies_users table
4. I map over an array of the movies' genres. For every genre I try the same as I did with the movie, it will either insert or do nothing depending on any possible duplicates. If it doesn't insert I look for the ID of the genre that's already in the table.
5. I then use the ID of the genre and the ID of the movie to insert a row into the genres_movies table

Personally, this looks like a horrible way to accomplish such a thing, so I feel I must be doing it wrong. The whole chaining of promises looks and feels awkward aswell. It works, but I assume there's a better way?

I'm planning on also using an actors table and an actors_movies tables, but I have no idea how I'd fit that in there as well (with the whole Promise.map thing).

So ultimately, my question is: if the code is right, how do I clean up the code OR if the code is not optimal at all, what would be a better way of accomplishing what I set out to do?

Comment: Code is no longer available: no way to adequately answer this question.